# Intellij error- Can not resolve symbol after invalidated cache

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

Can anyone please help me by going through the details mentioned below. Apologies for a lengthy post.

My very own automation framework is very simple, having a BaseClass which initializes the WebDriver instance and returns the WebDriver object. Then it has, listener class defined for generating reports using ExtentReport. There are page object classes for every page where I am running my test for validation. The class from which I am calling the Page objects for every page and running my Test methods is having the code to call initialize web driver from Base Class. Giving a screenshot of the project here:[image]

Few days back I noticed that the code I wrote to validate a new page "Page Object Address Book" is not getting triggered though I have a @Test method to invoke this validation. So, I did invalidate cache in Intellij by navigating File->Invalidate Cache.

After doing the invalidate cache operation, my entire project is failing to build now as I am seeing can not resolve symbol error in multiple places and also pom.xml is not recognized now. Hence, all dependencies that I have in pom.xml are not working which is resulting error to be displayed even selenium code, test ng code also. Giving some screeshots below.

[image]

[image]

Can someone pls help me to resolve this mess? This is simple framework which was working so far and suddenly everything is in a mess.

I tried to

a. Rebuild the project.
b. Change SDK version from 11 to 1.8

Comment: Could you please add your pom.xml? Which java target are you using?

Comment: You may try to remove all IDE related data (.idea folder and .iml files) and reimport project again.

Comment: @Marit, I am very new to this platform, not seeing any document attach option when adding comment. Pls guide how I can share pom xml file with you. However, my pom xml is very simple having dependecies of selenium, testNG and extent report.

Comment: @y.bedrov- Tried as suggested but it did not resolve the problem.

Comment: Is it reproducible with new sample project?

Comment: @y.bedrov- I have not created the exactly same new project but a different project where this issue did not occur.

Comment: Try closing all instances of IDEA and deleting the System Directory (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory). Then re-import your Project (Open -> double-click the root pom.xml -> Open as Project). Also how are you build the Project? Are you using the options from the Build Menu (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/compiling-applications.html) or Maven Tool Window (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-projects-tool-window.html)

Comment: I have created a new project to resolve the issue. That was more efficient than troubleshooting with old one:) Thanks everyone for their inputs!

Comment: @user3609098 For next time, copy the relevant code or config, like the (relevant section of the) pom.xml into your issue. You don't need to attach a file.